# Use c# expression to define server tag property value

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

Is it possible to set the property of a server tag from a c# expression, i.e. something like

```
<asp:TextBox Width='<%= [some c# expression] %>'/>
```

?

I though this would be pretty straightforward, but I can't get such an expression to run.

Thanks for any help

Ryan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You need to make sure the control runs server side (`runat="server"`), but depends on exactly what you are trying to evaluate in the expression.

So long as the expression returns a string, it should be fine.

```
<asp:TextBox id="txt" runat="server" Width='<%= (10 * 10).ToString() %>px'/>
```

This will result in a `width='100'` in the browser.

**Update:**

The above is completely wrong. You cannot put server side code render blocks (`<%%>` and `<%=%>`) in a server side control markup in this manner (since it already is a run server side).

In order to dynamically control the value, this needs to be done either in codebehind or within separate render blocks:

```
<%
  txt.Width = (10 * 10).ToString() + "px";
%>
<asp:TextBox id="txt" runat="server" />
```

See [this](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/307874-server-tags-cannot-contain-constructs) and [this](http://jblack.wordpress.com/2006/12/15/server-tags-cannot-contain-constructs/) for reference.

Comment: I'd also like to add that `<%= (10 * 10).ToString() %>` is a `Response.Write((10 * 10).ToString());`, just for better comprehension

Comment: This is odd. I tried your example: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxAmt" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "percent",  "{0:###.##}") %>' Width='<%= (10 * 10).ToString() %>'/>

But I get the error:Cannot create an object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit' from its string representation '<%= (10 * 10).ToString() %>' for the 'Width' property.

(The TextBox is in a databound grid)
I also tried a simple expression <%="40"%> and <%="40px"%>. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: @Ryan - `Width` is a `Unit`, so needs a number + a unit. My example should really be `Width='<%= (10 * 10).ToString() %>px'`

Comment: Hi @Oded, it still complained about not being a valid representation. I have boiled this down to the simplest form: <asp:Label runat="server" ID="tst" Text='<%="hi"%>' /> - this label doesn't display anything! (If I replace the expression with a literal, it displays). Thanks for your ongoing help.

Comment: @Ryan - just use `<asp:Label runat="server" ID="tst"><%= "hi"%></asp:Label>`

Comment: do not hesitate to get the actual tzpe of the object too, doing some <%# Container.DataItem %> or <%# Container.DataItem.GetType() %>, just to be sure of what you have..

Comment: @Ryan - answer updated. Looks like this is _not_ possible on server side controls. I thought, mistakenly that it _was_. You _can_ use binding expressions (`<%#%>`), but not code render blocks (`<%%>` and `<%=%>`).

Answer (score 1):

Beware of the type you bind to .

for instance

```
<asp:TextBox runat=server ID=C_TB_MyTB 
        Text=<%# MyText %> 
        Width=<%# MyWidth %>
    ></asp:TextBox>
```

Binding this textbox with

```
protected string MyWidth="300";
protected string MyText = "Bla bla bla...";
```

won't work , whereas :

```
protected int MyWidth=300;
protected string MyText = "Bla bla bla...";
```

will do...

good code to you,